# Programa lechero dev c++

Tags: dev-c++, codificación

Estoy realizando una practica en la cual un vendedor de leche debe saber la ganacia que tuvo por la venta de sus litros de leche, pero le pagan por galones.

El programa lo estoy desarrollando den DEV C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float Litros, gal, ganancia, precio;
    cout << "Ingresa cantidad de litros de leche vendidos:" << endl;
    cin >> Litros;
    cout ,, "Precios por galon:" <<endl;
    cin >> precio;
    gal+ (Litros/3.785);
    ganancia= (precios*gal);
    cout << "Ganancia por venta del dia es de= " <<ganancia<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Me arroja error en el cout de la linea 8, exactamente entre las 2 comas. También en el <

```
C:\Users\*****\programa_lechero.cpp:10:33: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [19]' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'
  cout ,, "Precios por galon:" <<endl;
                                 ^
C:\Users\******\programa_lechero.cpp:13:13: error: 'precios' was not declared in this scope
  ganancia= (precios*gal);
```

Comment: Tienes que aprender a interpretar lo que te dice el compilador. Te está marcandote el error de usar `,,` en lugar de `<<`. También te dice que la variable `precios` no ha sido definida dentro del ámbito del `main`. Y es cierto pues tú has definido la variable `precio` (en singular).

Comment: Eyllanesc muchas gracias por la guia, habia pasado por alto estos detalles del compilador y no sup como intepretarlos. Ya corregi el fallo.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores.

1. Las dos comas no van, en vez de ellas va `<<`.
2. `gal = (Litros/3.785);` en vez de gal+ (Litros/3.785);
3. ganancia= (**precios** *gal); debe tener `precio` en singular.

El código quedaría así.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float Litros, gal, ganancia, precio;
    cout << "Ingresa cantidad de litros de leche vendidos:" << endl;
    cin >> Litros;
    cout << "Precios por galon:" <<endl;
    cin >> precio;
    gal = (Litros/3.785);
    ganancia = (precio*gal);
    cout << "Ganancia por venta del dia es de= " <<ganancia<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: eaportugal, muchas gracias, ya compare tu muestra del código contra todo mi código solo para darme cuenta de los errores. Ya compiló y corrió sin problemas.